# Javascript: A couple of JS questions

Tags: javascript, createelement

I am learning this stuff and trying to understand it, so am using this instead of innerhtml.

My code:

```
  <script>
function load() {
"use strict";

var t  = document.createElement("table"),
    tb = document.createElement("tbody"),
    tr = document.createElement("tr"),
    td = document.createElement("td");

    var b = document.createElement("b");
b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" name!"));
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello"));
td.appendChild(b); 

    t.style.width = "100%";
    t.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';
    t.border=1;

    // note the reverse order of adding child        
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tb.appendChild(tr);
    t.appendChild(tb);

   // more code to populate table rows and cells
   document.getElementById("theBlah").appendChild(t);
alert(t.innerHTML);
   }
</script>
 </head>

 <body  onload="load()">
```

problem is , `onload()` does not display the `<table>` tag, it displays from `<tbody>` instead... any idea why?

And finally, in this code:

```
var t  = document.createElement("table"),

 tb = document.createElement("tbody"),
 tr = document.createElement("tr"),
 td = document.createElement("td");
```

even though I am using the Var keyword just for t, and not for the others, why is it not complaining even though "use strict" is on? In fact if I add a "var" in front of "tb, "tr", "td" *then* it throws an error...
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) innerHTML is just that. It's `inner`. It doesn't contain the HTML of the element itself, but all the html that is within that element. There is a property called outerHTML too, but it's not included in Firefox. The only cross browser way to get outerHTML is to wrap the node in a new parent node and grab that nodes innerHTML. You can't just grab the current parent's innerHTML (You have to make a new parent) unless you're sure the element has no siblings, because if you do the siblings will included.

2) You are using commas to separate your variable decorations. That is the same as using semi-colons and putting `var` on each line.

Comment: What you said about innerHTML was very true, so I switched browsers and in Chrome it gave me the inner and outer while in FF only inner worked. Either way, I got my answers! Have a good day!

Comment: @Jumac, you're welcome :) Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you, by clicking the check-mark under the vote count :)

Answer (score 0):

InnerHtml is faster even though it's not in the spec. Its just the inner html like the above person said and not an element.

Using one Var and commas to separate your variable decorations is a good idea, 
 1. to reduce file size,
 2. to declare all variables at the top. ([to avoid hoisting problem](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html))